# Bootstrap 3 navbar not showing correctly when uploaded to server

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I've create a navbar in Bootstrap 3, when i execute the html locally, it displays as intended like this:

[image]

When i try and upload it to my server, it shows like this:

[image]

even on my own device. Will including media queries help solve the problem?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head> 
    <title>Cryptoskeptic</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/font-awesome.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
    <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/7468f01c54.js"></script>   
</head>

<body>

<nav class="navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="nav navbar-nav">
            <a href="#" class="navbar-brand"><img src="img/nav-logo.png"></a>
        </div>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right user">
            <li><i class="fa fa-user fa-3x"></i></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

```
body{
    background-color: black;}

.navbar-inverse{
    background:transparent;
    }

.navbar-brand {
transform: translateX(-50%);
left: 50%;
position: absolute;}

.user{
position: absolute;
right: 275px;
color: white;
transform: translateY(50%);}
```

Here is the image being used:
[Navbar-logo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ImAmp.png)

Here are some console errors that i'm getting:
[image]

Comment: Maybe it has something to do with the image itself ?

Comment: @Leon, i've added the image in the edit. Kindly take a look and suggest possible solutions.

Comment: It kinda looks like some CSS isn't loading - possibly Bootstrap. Your user icon is in a `<li>` element and it's getting a bullet point when it shouldn't be. Do you get any errors in your console when the page is on the server?

Answer (score 0):

From what we can tell, it seems that your CSS files may not be loading, as you're getting some default styling on the `li` element.

You should check that the path as `css/bootstrap.css` is loading in fact correctly. If it's not, you should check the Console ([here's how to open it on Chrome](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/)) and you should see an Error.

Just to clarify, if you upload everything perfectly, it has to look exactly as it looks locally.

Comment: i've double checked to see that the uploaded directory as the same as my local, i've added the visible console errors in the edit.